# Sorting for each group based if it has a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables. first is company table which contains the company ranking and the second table is storage units which indicates which storage belong to which company, ranking of each storage unit, and capacity of each storage unit. during processing, I only need the highest ranking storage unit belonging to the highest rated companies. take for example below:

[company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pINhx.png)

| CompanyID | Company |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

storage units

[storageunit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnZ7S.png)

expected result:

[expected1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLKWa.png)

when storage units hve been updated:

[storageunit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDn5E.png)

then result is as follows:

[expected2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26MfO.png)

the current sorting being done is this:
INNER JOIN storage_units AS s
ON s.companyID = p.id
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY s.rank, p.rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
it works the first time but on second run if having this storage units table:
[storageunit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDn5E.png)

, it yields this result:
[currentres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C5Kb.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).   See the example of my edit which makes the table `Company` so much better readable.

Comment: And please give the complete SQL statement, and not just the `INNER JOIN...` part...

Comment: Thanks for creating a dbfiddle, but you problem description is not clear to /me (probably a language thing...), and I am not wanting to debug your stored procedure `storage_update`.